# Error while using Invoke-RestMethod in Powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am using a `Invoke-RestMethod` to post to a site.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $dest -Proxy $proxyurl -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials 
                  -Body $postparm -Method Post -Verbose
```

Payload: $postparm = @{pId= 'PMP03'; factTypes= "{sported='true';posit='1';Coins='1';Withdraw='100';Notes='100';PerMonth='101';Indicator='Yes'}"}

But I get the this error shown below. I tried adding content-type "application/json" because the webpage request header says content-type as application/json. This returns me Bad request (400)

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
>   At C:\SolutionFinderHealthCheck\Check for URL.ps1:36 char:13
>   + $response = Invoke-RestMethod $natdest -Proxy $natproxyurl -ProxyUseD ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

How to resolve this?

Comment: I think you've found part of your answer. Almost certainly you need to send well-formed JSON via the POST. The 400 tells you that it didn't like what that payload had in it. Focus on that. [Edit] the question and show what the payload looks like.

Comment: Here is the payload @jdv
$postparm = @{pId= 'PMP03'; factTypes= "{sported='true';posit='1';Coins='1';Withdraw='100';Notes='100';PerMonth='101';Indicator='Yes'}"}

Comment: That should be in the Question, which you can add with an [edit]. Then you have to find out what the server is expecting. We don't know because we don't control that server. One assumes that the endpoint requirements are documented...

Comment: @jdv I added the payload to question as well, the server is expecting application/json but still I am getting error.

Comment: BTW, that is not valid JSON.

Comment: After this I used payload | ConvertTo-Json

Comment: And are you getting valid JSON from that? Work from the known to the unknown, proving your assertions each time. But, at the end of the day we don't know what this endpoint wants from you. One presumes you are reading published documentation so you are coding to a specification?

Comment: @jdv You were right my payload was the problem. Thanks a ton. Issue resolved.